# android:style value not found error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-theme, aide-ide

I have the following line of code in my manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

I have developed my app primarily using AIDE, and in AIDE, this line runs fine(compiles and works). However, the other day I moved my app to eclipse, which for some reason gives me this error (same files, I have made no changes)

```
No resource found that matches the given name Theme.Holo.Light (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light').
```

Now had this not worked in AIDE I would assume this line is wrong, but I functioned perfectly. What is more interesting, is that when I change the api level to something below 11(when holo was introduced) I get a second error

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light requires api level 11
```

Now this second error seems to suggest to me that the theme exists(and that eclipse can find it), but even when the api level is 11, the first error still persists. Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Interestingly, intellij has no complaints

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to **clean and build** your project..

If that doesn't work then

**Right click on project --> Select ANdroid tools --> Add Support library**

then clean and build the project..

Hope this helps..

Comment: Cleaning did not work... Where is the project that I am meant to right click on? The only project I see is in the menu bar

Comment: @Raghunandan - no, will that help me with my problem? I guess I should probably update never the less

Comment: @jcw not sure just asked for clarification that's all

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this - 
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme`